# Does contour integral over $\mathbb{R}$ give a step function?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have the following integral
$$ \int \frac{dx}{2\pi i} \frac{1}{(x+ia)^2+b^2} $$
where $x$ is a real variable and we integrate in the real axis from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. I am also given the fact that
$$
\int dx \frac{1}{(x + ia)^2+b^2}=\frac{\pi}{|b|}\theta(|b|-|a|)
$$
integrating again in the real line and where $\theta$ is the step function. I want to know why the latter integral gives me this theta function and if I am right that the first integral would then give me
$$
\frac{-i}{|b|}\theta(|b|-|a|)
$$

Comment: do you know how to compute $\int_C \frac{1}{z^2-\alpha^2} dz$ where $C$ is the upper infinite radius semi-circle plus the real line to close the contour, and $\alpha$ is not real ?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure really, I have not seen this.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you have seen the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: I know that $\int \frac{dz}{f(z)}=2\pi i \sum_{k}\text{Res}f(a_k)$. I just googled Cauchy formula but I still don't see this $\theta$ function arising.

Comment: $\int_C \frac{1}{(z+ia)^2 + b^2)} dz =\int_C \frac{1}{(z+ia+ib)(z+ia-ib)} dz$ suppose that $Im(a+b) > 0$ but $Im(a-b) < 0$ hence there is only one pole of $\frac{1}{(z+ia+ib)(z+ia-ib)}$ inside the contour and $\int_C \frac{1}{(z+ia+ib)(z+ia-ib)} dz = 2 i \pi \frac{1}{ia+ib+ia-ib}$. if $Im(a+b) < 0$ and $Im(a-b) < 0$ then $\frac{1}{(z+ia+ib)(z+ia-ib)}$ is holomorphic inside the contour and $\int_C \frac{1}{(z+ia+ib)(z+ia-ib)} dz = 0$. the third case is $a-b > 0$ and $a+b > 0$ I let you treat it.

Comment: Is this 3rd case when the $\theta$ function appears?

Comment: @user1952009 Is this 3rd case when the $\theta$ function appears? I apologise, but I am very confused.. Also, how do I choose contour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I(a,b)$ be integral of interest given by

$$I(a,b)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+ia)^2+b^2}\,dx \tag 1$$

We assume that $b\ne0$ else the integral is trivially $0$ for $a\ne 0$.

Note that the function $f(z)$, defined as $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+ia)^2+b^2}$ has first-order poles at $z=-i(a\pm b)$ with corresponding residues given by

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(z+ia)^2+b^2},z=-i(a\pm b)\right)=\mp \frac{1}{2ib} \tag 2$$

Next, $C$ be the closed contour comprised of the real line segment from $-R$ to $R$ and the semi-circle in the upper-half plane, with radius $R$ and centered at the origin.  Define $J(a,b)$ as the closed-contour integral around $C$ of $f(z)$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
J(a,b)&=\oint_C \frac{1}{(z+ia)^2+b^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{(x+ia)^2+b^2}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{(Re^{i\phi}+ia)^2+b^2}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi \tag 3
\end{align}$$

In the limit as $R\to \infty$, the first integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ tends to $I(a,b)$ as given in $(1)$ while the second integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ tends to $0$.

Moreover, the residue theorem guarantees that $J(a,b)$ is $2\pi i$ times the residues from the poles enclosed in $C$ as given in $(2)$.  We have four cases to examine.

---

> **Case 1:**  Neither pole is in the upper-half plane.

Here, if $\text{Re}(a-b)>0$ and $\text{Re}(a+b)>0$, then no pole is enclosed and $I(a,b)=0$.

Note that this corresponds to $|\text{Re}(a)|>|\text{Re}(b)|$.

---

> **Case 2:**  Both poles are enclosed in the upper-half plane.

Here, if $\text{Re}(a-b)<0$ and $\text{Re}(a+b)<0$, then both poles are enclosed.  The sum of the residues is $0$ and $I(a,b)=0$.

Note that this also corresponds to $|\text{Re}(a)|>|\text{Re}(b)|$.

---

> **Case 3:**  Only the pole at $z=-i(a-b)$ is enclosed in the upper-half plane.

Here, if $\text{Re}(a-b)<0$ and $\text{Re}(a+b)>0$, then only the pole at $z=-i(a-b)$ is enclosed.  The residue from this pole is $\frac{1}{2ib}$ and $I(a,b)=\frac{\pi}{b}$.

Note that this corresponds to $|\text{Re}(b)|>|\text{Re}(a)|$.

---

> **Case 4:**  Only the pole at $z=-i(a+b)$ is enclosed in the upper-half plane.

Here, if $\text{Re}(a-b)>0$ and $\text{Re}(a+b)<0$, then only the pole at $z=-i(a+b)$ is enclosed.  The residue from this pole is $-\frac{1}{2ib}$ and $I(a,b)=-\frac{\pi}{b}$.

Note that this also corresponds to $|\text{Re}(b)|>|\text{Re}(a)|$.

---

Putting all $4$ cases together, we see that if $|\text{Re}(a)|>|\text{Re}(b)|$, $I(a,b)=0$, while if $|\text{Re}(b)|>|\text{Re}(a)|$, then $I(a,b)=\pm \frac{\pi}{b}$.  In addition, for Case $3$, we see that $\text{Re}(b)>0$, while for Case $4$, $\text{Re}(b)<0$.  Thus, we can finally write

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I(a,b)=\text{sgn}\left(\text{Re}(b)\right)\,\left(\frac{\pi}{b}\right)\,\theta\left(|\text{Re}(b)|-|\text{Re}(a)|\right)} \tag 4$$

where

$$\text{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1&,x>0\\\\0&,x=0\\\\1&,x< 0 \end{cases}$$

and

$$\theta(x)=\begin{cases}1&,x>0\\\\0&,x\le 0 \end{cases}$$

For real-valued $a$ and $b$, $(4)$ simplifies to

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I(a,b)=\left(\frac{\pi}{|b|}\right)\,\theta\left(|b|-|a|\right)} $$

as was to be shown!

Comment: this seems quite non-trivial (as for example easier cases of Cauchy's integral). Is there some nice reference for it? Also, when I Google it, it seems to not be a known or at least a fundamental identity.

Comment: @Marion I had not seen this precise integral, with complex parameters, before yesterday.  Of course, we might have tried solving it using the arctangent function.  That is, $\int \frac{1}{(x+ia)^2+b^2}\,dx =\frac1b \arctan((x+ia)/b)+C$.  Then, one must be careful to cut the plane appropriately to handle the multiple branches of the complex arctangent function.

Comment: would you like to also help me with this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746275/can-i-switch-to-polar-coordinates-if-my-function-has-complex-poles?noredirect=1#comment3563843_1746275 please? I would like to ask for your advice.