# Can I switch to polar coordinates if my function has complex poles?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polar-coordinates, complex-integration

You can think this of the following as a 3d QFT where we try to calculate the self-energy of two fields. $I$ is a this external self-energy and let us assume it does not depend on the loop momenta which I denote a $\vec{x}=(x,y)$.
Consider the following propagator 
$$
P(\vec{r}) = \frac{x-ia}{2i^2[\,(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2+(z-ic)^2]\,} \,\, \gamma_i.
$$
Then we want to calculate
$$
I(x) = \int \frac{\,dx \,dy\, dz}{(2\pi)^3} \text{Tr} \left( \frac{x-ia}{2i^2[\,(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2+(z-ic)^2]\,}\gamma_x \gamma_x  \right),
$$
where Tr$(\gamma_i \gamma_j)=2\delta_{ij}$. Therefore 
I am trying to resolve the following integral where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b,c$ are constants (internal self-energies if you wish) in $\mathbb{R}$.  Then, after simplifying the propagator $P(x,y)$ we end up with the following expression for the $x$ component: 
$$
I = \frac{1}{2i^2} \int \frac{dxdy}{(2\pi)^2} (x-ia) \int \frac{dz}{2\pi} \frac{1}{[\,(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2+(z-ic)^2]\,}
$$
but it can be shown that 
$$
\int \frac{dq}{(q+iv)^2+w^2} = \frac{\pi}{|w|}\theta(|w|-|v|). 
$$
(e.g. see here [Does contour integral over $\mathbb{R}$ give a step function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741492/does-contour-integral-over-mathbbr-give-a-step-function))
Thus we get that for $|(y-ib)^2+(x-ia)^2|>|a|$, $\theta=1$ (for this is what we are interested about) and then we are left with
$$
I = \frac{1}{4i^2} \int \frac{dxdy}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{(x-ia)}{|(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2|}.  
$$
The question is wether I can make the transformation
$$
(x-ia) = q \cos \theta 
$$
$$
(y-ib) = q \sin \theta
$$
in polar coordinates. Then $dx dy = qdqd\theta$ and the previous integral becomes, assuming $|q|>0$,
$$
I = \int_0^{\infty} dq \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \frac{q \cos \theta}{|q|} =0.
$$
Is this correct? I am confused since one can find complex poles in the $I$. If not, what would the correct way to resolve this be? I have a suspicion that this integral should indeed give zero but how can we find this?

Comment: The original integrand has no pole unless $a = b = 0$, as $x, y$ are real, and so never come near to $ia, ib$. As for your substitution: solve for $q, \theta$. You will see that $\theta$ cannot be real in general, so you cannot integrate it from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Hi. I indeed $x,y $ are real. But I do not understand why the substitution makes no sense. Then wjat would be a way to resolve this integral?

Comment: Solve for $\theta$ by taking the ratio: $$\tan \theta = \frac{y-ib}{x-ia}$$ If the ratio of $y$ to $x$ is not the same as the ratio of $b$ to $a$, then the fraction is not real, which means $\theta$ is not real either.

Comment: Some context has been added @AccidentalFourierTransform so maybe you can write in a bit more detail why you argue that this integral is zero. I am still confused about the "oddness" argument. Additionally, apparently the polar coordinate transformation is not well defined.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks, I do see this. The question remains though how one can resolve this integral which I suspect it is zero. Do you have any comments/suggestions or so on on how to resolve it?

Comment: Your first problem is that the function is not well-defined. Because the value in the square root is complex, you need to specify which branch of the square root you are using. And then you have additional issues. Quite frankly, I suspect you made some errors deriving this integral. This does not look like something I expect to see out of a physics problem. You may want to double-check your work before this point before putting more effort into finding this value.

Comment: Ok, I will try to add details here so that things become more clear. Please, let me know if you wish, about what you think.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have added more background. The starting point is the function $P(\vec{r})$. Note that the integral does not depend on $\vec{r}$. I do not see some obvious mistake in any of the steps.

Comment: Note that in the answer to the other thread,$$\int \frac{dq}{(q+iv)^2+w^2} = \frac{\pi}{|w|}\theta(|w|-|v|)$$ only holds when $v$ and $w$ are real. The form for complex values is more complicated. But in your application here, $w$ is complex

Comment: @PaulSinclair Indeed, you are right. May I ask how you would suggest to resolve this problem? I am very stuck with it.

Comment: Use equation (4) from the other thread, which applies to complex values. I will try to work it out if I can, but my time is limited, and the internet connection where I am right now is sporadic at best, so it may be friday before I can do so.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks a lot, I had the impression I was using equation (4), this is how I got the denominator in my last equation $|q|$. It would be great if you could work this out it would be very helpful for me. Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back. Things have been hectic. You were not using (4). you were using the further unnumbered equation that was derived from (4) that *only holds when $v, w$ are both real*, which is not the case here. You need to use the equation *that is actually tagged as (4) on the very same line* in that post when $v, w$ are not real. Unfortunately, when applied to $z$ in your full equation above, this results in a really nasty integral in $x, y$: To apply it, $v = c$ and $w = \sqrt{(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2}$ with $\text{Re}(w) > 0$.