# Self-energy integral at (complex) polar coordinates

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

You can think this of the following as a 3d QFT where we try to calculate the self-energy of two fields. $I$ is a this external self-energy and let us assume it does not depend on the loop momenta which I denote a $\vec{x}=(x,y)$.
Consider the following propagator 
$$
P(\vec{r}) = \frac{x-ia}{2i^2[\,(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2+(z-ic)^2]\,} \,\, \gamma_i
$$
Then we want to calculate
$$
I(x) = \int \frac{\,dx \,dy\, dz}{(2\pi)^3} \text{Tr} \left( \frac{x-ia}{2i^2[\,(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2+(z-ic)^2]\,}\gamma_x \gamma_x  \right)
$$
Where Tr$(\gamma_i \gamma_j)=2\delta_{ij}$. Therefore 
I am trying to resolve the following integral where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b,c$ are constants (internal self-energies if you wish) in $\mathbb{R}$.  Then, after simplifying the propagator $P(x,y)$ we end up with the following expression for the $x$ component: 
$$
I = \frac{1}{2i^2} \int \frac{dxdy}{(2\pi)^2} (x-ia) \int \frac{dz}{2\pi} \frac{1}{[\,(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2+(z-ic)^2]\,}
$$
but it can be shown that 
$$
\int \frac{dq}{(q+iv)^2+w^2} = \frac{\pi}{|w|}\theta(|w|-|v|). 
$$
[e.g. see here [Does contour integral over $\mathbb{R}$ give a step function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741492/does-contour-integral-over-mathbbr-give-a-step-function) ]
Thus we get that for $|(y-ib)^2+(x-ia)^2|>|a|$, $\theta=1$ (for this is what we are interested about) and then we are left with
$$
I = \frac{1}{4i^2} \int \frac{dxdy}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{(x-ia)}{|(x-ia)^2+(y-ib)^2|}  
$$

The question is wether I can make the transformation
$$
(x-ia) = q \cos \theta 
$$
$$
(y-ib) = q \sin \theta
$$
in polar coordinates. Then $dx dy = qdqd\theta$ and the previous integral becomes, assuming $|q|>0$,
$$
I = \int_0^{\infty} dq \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \frac{q \cos \theta}{|q|} =0
$$
Is this correct? I am confused since one can find complex poles in the $I$. If not, what would the correct way to resolve this be? I have a suspicion that this integral should indeed give zero but how can we find this?

Comment: if you make the change of variable $x\to x+ia$ you'll see that the original integral is odd w.r.t. $x\to -x$, and therefore the result is zero.

Comment: I am puzzled, the original variable is already $x-ia$.

Comment: yes, I know. So what? Let $\tilde x\equiv x-ia,\mathrm d\tilde x=\mathrm dx$ and integrate. The integral is zero because the integrand is odd w.r.t $\tilde x\to-\tilde x$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I see what you mean. Ok, right, thanks. I am just curious if the polar coordinates transformation that also yields a zero is ok.

Comment: yes, it is also ok

Comment: If the details don't matter, then the burden is on you to provide the details on the integral. For instance, x,y,a, and b are all real, so the argument to the square root is complex. When the square root function has a real root you can take the positive square root, when it has a complex input there is no obvious way to pick one of the two complex numbers that squares to to give the input complex number. So we need a branch of the square root. And your substitution makes no sense because your limits indicate q and theta are real, but that requires a=b=0 so on both cases you ignored complex #s

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform An improper integral is a limit of finite length definite integrals. And when you do a u substitution on a definite integral you need to change the limits as well as the differential, in your case to having complex limits of integration. So you don't have an integral from say -5 to +5 they go from two numbers whose real parts are negatives but that have the same imaginary part. In other words two numbers that aren't negatives of each other. If you answer in comments people can't edit your answers or downvote wrong answers. Comments are for seeking clarification.

Comment: @Timaeus we are talking QFT here. In QFT any integral with odd integrand is taken as zero even if the integral is improper (in this case, the integral is UV divergent). OP's integral is formally divergent, but in any regularisation scheme this integral **is** zero.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform If you want to make an *answer* that takes the physics into account, please do so. Since the OP might have broken a physical integral into mathematical parts and asked us about merely one of the parts, I don't see how you know this applies to the mere part. Yes it is divergent. But it isn't odd, and we don't know how it relates to a physical integral because we weren't given that information. Basically we were told it didn't matter and your real answer in comments is that it does matter. Your first answer made it seem like math said it was zero, but physics says 0.

Comment: @Timaeus the question is devoid of physics, and that's why the first thing I did was to vote to close (as "belongs on math.SE"). But on a second thought, I believe the integral is very bad defined even for physicists standards, so I'm not sure what we are supposed to do. Maybe if OP included some physics into the question we could say something (for example, there is a high chance that $a,b$ are infinitesimal). As you say, if $a,b$ are finite the integral is not necessarily zero, but in any case it is very bad defined and I cant make any sense out of it.

Comment: Hi. I will add some physics context next thing in the morning. Im the meanwhile indeed the integral is divergent as AccidentalFourierTransform says. Still now I am confused on wether the integral should be zero or not. The idea is that this integral represents the self energy of an interaction. This is an integral over the momenta, the terms $a,b $ are self energies of internal momenta.

Comment: @Timaeus I have added background. Please check if you wish.

Comment: It is the exact same question. I am not sure why there is too times..

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I have a solution for the problem. But since it is closed I will retain.